# I want to make 4 radio button and 1 go button, I want when i check any one radio button and then click on go button then the url will be changeded

Tags: javascript, url, radio-button

World! google
facebook
yahoo
twitter
[click to Go✓](https://facebook.com) if(document.getElementById('google').checked = true) { document.getElementById('btn') .setAttribute("href", "https://google.com"); } else { document.getElementById('btn') .setAttribute("href", "https://example.com"); } if(document.getElementById('facebook').checked = true) { document.getElementById('btn') .setAttribute("href", "https://facebook.com"); } else { document.getElementById('btn') .setAttribute("href", "https://example.com"); } if(document.getElementById('yahoo').checked = true) { document.getElementById('btn') .setAttribute("href", "https://yahoo.com"); } else { document.getElementById('btn') .setAttribute("href", "https://example.com"); } if(document.getElementById('twitter').checked = true) { document.getElementById('btn') .setAttribute("href", "https://twitter.com"); } else { document.getElementById('btn') .setAttribute("href", "https://example.com"); }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...... You just have to use window.location dom manipulation function of javascript to redirect the user. You can use if-else statement to check which site was selected using querySelector or by any other means. Here is my code for it.

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="site" id="google" /> Google <br />
    <input type="radio" name="site" id="facebook" /> Facebook <br />
    <input type="radio" name="site" id="yahoo" /> Yahoo <br />
    <input type="radio" name="site" id="twitter" /> Twitter <br />
    <hr />

    <button type="submit" onclick="redirect()">Click to go</button>
</form>
```

javascript code below :-

```
function redirect() {
        if (document.getElementById('google').checked) {
            document.write("Redirecting...");
            window.location = ("https://www.google.com");
        }

        else if (document.getElementById('facebook').checked) {
            document.write("Redirecting...");
            window.location = ("https://www.facebook.com");
        }

        else if (document.getElementById('yahoo').checked) {
            document.write("Redirecting...");
            window.location = ("https://www.yahoo.com");
        }

        else if (document.getElementById('twitter').checked) {
            document.write("Redirecting...");
            window.location = ("https://www.twitter.com");
        }

        else {
            return;
        }
    }
```